# Why did I set the y attribute value in d3 and it did not actually take effect;

Tags: javascript, d3.js

code show as below：

```
d3.select('#points').append('use')
    .attr('id', 'yd')
    .attr('type', 'point')
    .attr('x', 70)
    .attr('y', 480)
    .attr('class', 'origin')
    .attr('xlink:href','#point')
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on('start', dragstarteds)
        .on('drag', draggeds)
        .on('end', dragendeds));
console.log(d3.select('#yd'));
console.log(d3.select('#yd').attr('y'));
```

The two results obtained by console are as follows:
[1.The set x attribute takes effect but the y attribute does not take effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUmMb.png)

[2.But the value obtained through d3.select('#yd').attr('y') is exactly the value of the y attribute I set (80)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzvsQ.png)

[The y property value shown on the page is 490 instead of the 480 I set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAI0E.png)

I didn't modify this y attribute value elsewhere. Can someone help me to see what the problem is?

Comment: Hard to say. your example is not reproductible. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Unless you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue this comes down to guessing.

Comment: Voting to close as off topic: *"Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself"*. Also, you're mixing `80` and `480`, which one is correct?